# Regex: Match any string but one ending with thanks/

Tags: regex, google-analytics, regex-lookarounds, goal-tracking

I am attempting to set up a goal funnel in Google Analytics.  It is for an online quote request system that we want to track.  Basically all the pages that contain the quote request form have unique dynamically generated urls that are similar.  The form of the URL is:

> /quoterequest/categoryone/categorytwo/productname/

I have regex that works for tracking that:

```
^/quoterequest/([A-Za-z0-9/-]+)?
```

Today we added a thank you page after the user submits the form.  The URL is always the same for that:

> /quoterequest/thanks/

I would like to modify the above regex so that it continues to match any of the Quote Request URLs, but NOT that thank you URL. I have been trying different variations, including t. he negative look ahead,but unfortunately I am not very experienced with regex and I think I've been doing it completely incorrectly.  Can anyone give me some insight as to the correct method of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
^\/quoterequest\/(?!thanks\/?$)(?:([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\/?)*$
```

[**See it**](http://www.rubular.com/r/8uHA9Qpwry)

Comment: That worked beautifully! Thanks! Unfortunately,Google kept throwing an error every time I used it.  I went a different route for the goal funnel, but there are other applications in which I will need to use this, so thank you very much!